# DataGrid Tab to commit

Tags: wpf, datagrid

The .NET DataGrid [document at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says

> All edits in a row are committed when you move to another row or press ENTER while the row is in edit mode.

It is my impression this is not sufficiently common that users expect this. I feel it necessary to implement a status text box to write:

> "Edits are committed with the Enter key. The tab key will commit edits if you tab beyond the end of the row."

Does DataGrid support any alternative behaviour that is more WYSIWYG in that every tab commits the edit? By support, I mean that I very much prefer if it's just a matter of enabling an alternative behaviour and not something more complicated and prone to break or turn obsolete in the future. My prejudice is that it is not worth it to me to capture keystrokes.

Comment: I guess UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus should do it.... not tested though, please check and let us know ----   `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Line1" Binding="{Binding Path=Item, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="50"/>`

Comment: Similar to your suggestion I did this `((column as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding as Binding).UpdateSourceTrigger = System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;` This works for string properties. A null reference happens for enum properties.This is a good solution if you can avoid enums.

Comment: `foreach (var column in myDataGrid.Columns)` should precede the text in my comment above.

Comment: how are you handling/bingind enums ? they need extra effort as compared to strings

Comment: `<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="CurrencyCodeEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type System:Enum}" >
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="InterfaceListSchemaNamespace:CurrencyCodeEnum" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>` That's how I bind the enums. Also necessary is a definition for the namespace in the Window XAML element. `xmlns:InterfaceListSchemaNamespace="clr-namespace:InterfaceListSchema;assembly=InterfaceListSchema"`